# Tensorflow lite and its deployment to android studio

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, keras

I have converted my keras model into *.tflite file, after trying to figure out how to use tensorflow lite on the android studio, I am struggle at the point of pre-processing data from my android phone (or from my camera) then making classification (as it is a cnn models with 4 softmax output nodes, input images size is (1,256,256,3)). Since tensorflow and other sites did not mention more information about the input and output (their types,...etc) of the tflite.run(input, output) to generating prediction from images that could came from the phone's gallery or it's camera, and I am also new to Java application developing, hope you guys could help me to figure out and complete the application, thanks. (sorry for my bad grammar)

I have included tflite model, open image from the gallery but don't know how to pre-processing it as Java is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a better understanding of how to perform the pre-processing for image files (atleast for ImageNet-style models) from the TFLite Android example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L226).

They convert a Bitmap using this function:

```
private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imgData == null) {
      return;
    }
    imgData.rewind();
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    // Convert the image to floating point.
    int pixel = 0;
    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < getImageSizeX(); ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < getImageSizeY(); ++j) {
        final int val = intValues[pixel++];
        addPixelValue(val);
      }
    }
    long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: " + (endTime - startTime));
  }
```

The pixel preprocessing to be precise is done as follows:

```
protected void addPixelValue(int pixelValue) {
    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
  }
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, by the way, what is Image mean and image std :(( I saw this code yesterday and decided not to take it, instead of that I take the bit operations just like yours above and divided by 255.f and it's seem to working well.